# Json + google maps v3: display multiple json fields

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

just a quick question.. I have this map and need to add more fields *Confirmed=seen in the json file... cheers!!

```
    $.getJSON( 'geojson/test.json', function(data) { 
    $.each( data.features, function(i, marker) {


        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),


            'bounds': true 
        }).click(function() {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': (marker.donor)}, this);
        });
    });
});
```

index-->http://gk5tudio.cu.cc/bin/json/index.html and 
json -->http://gk5tudio.cu.cc/bin/json/test.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest putting the information in some `div` elements and then adding that to content value.

```
.click(function() {
  var html = '<div>' + marker.donor + '</div><div>Confirmed: ' + marker.confirmed + '</div>';
  $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': html }, this);
});
```

Comment: Andy your a pimp!! can i hit you with another question??

Comment: Sure. Can't guarantee I'll be able to answer it tho.

Comment: ok so ive got this map and want to add a pie chart for each marker using highcharts.js using the same json format but a different file..

Comment: @gk5tudio, not really my area. I suggest having a stab it it yourself, and if you run into trouble, ask another question on Stack Overflow. Glad I could help otherwise. Make sure you click on the tick next to my answer if you're happy with what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

is your question how to add marker.confirmed to the infobox ?

try:

```
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),'bounds': true }).click(function() { $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': (marker.donor+''+marker.confirmed)}, this); }); });
```